# Function returning emptying String when using Notification and observers?

Tags: ios, swift

In the following code I want to return a string from first controller to third controller. But it returns an empty string, when trying by notification and observers.

**First View Controller**

```
override function ViewDidLoad(){   
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:    
     #selector(token(notification:)), name: .token, object: nil)

}


@objc func token (notification:Notification) -> String!{

        return self.token! //return token
    }


extension Notification.Name {

    static let token = Notification.Name("Token")
}
```

**ThirdViewController***

```
  override function ViewDidLoad(){   
     let token = NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .token, object: nil)
        print(token) // () printing empty

}
```

Comment: maybe it's because when you post notification at that time third controller doesn't exist, if you want to pass variable you can use prepareForSegue func to pass object forward or delegate methods to handle object changes anywhere

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik  when I am in third controller I would like to get variable value that is in first Controller

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you problem correctly you want to pass object from first controller to third, you can use segue for it. This is the example how you can pass it to second, the same thing to pass forward from second to third

```
@IBAction func goForawrd(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "second", sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "second" {
        let vc = segue.destination as? SecondViewController
        vc?.object = yourObjectYouWantToPass
    }
}
```

or if you don't want to use segue you can use next code

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second")
    secondVC.object = yourObjectYouWantToPass
```

don't forget to set viewController identifier before

Answer (score 0):

This 
`NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .token, object: nil)` doesn't return anything you get the observer wrongly it posts the notification and if there is an observer it'll be forwarded to it , so this flow occurs

1-

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .token, object: nil)
```

2-

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:    
 #selector(token(notification:)), name: .token, object: nil
```

3-

```
@objc func token (notification:Notification) {}
```

if you need to send data from first to second set it when you segue/present/push , if you need to send data from second to first use a delegate

Comment: I am sending to third controller

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you are printing nil since that is not the value of the token just the reference for the post method.

Since it is not a bidirectional thing you cannot retrieve the value there.

If you want to achieve this by notifications these are the required steps:

1. Send a notification about you need a token
2. When notification arrived on first controller grab what you need and send another notification with the value you need, and handle it where you need.

First View Controller

```
override function ViewDidLoad(){   
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:    
     #selector(token(notification:)), name: .tokenGet, object: nil)

}


@objc func token (notification:Notification) {
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .tokenSet, object: token)
    }


extension Notification.Name {

    static let tokenGet = Notification.Name("TokenGet")
    static let tokenSet = Notification.Name("TokenSet")
}
```

ThirdViewController*

```
override function ViewDidLoad(){
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:    
     #selector(token(notification:)), name: .tokenSet, object: nil)
     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .tokenGet, object: nil)

}

func tokenSet(notification: Notification) {
/// here you can get the value from notification
}
```

Note that i would NOT do in this way. Pass the token through the view controllers or create a class which is responsible for token handling and pass that around.

Comment: so, passing class instance or pass token is safe than using notification